# GridView Data Binding

Tags: asp.net

I have  an empty field in a GridView and all what i want to do is to populate this empty field from another control which is DetailView control.  When the page loads first, the Detail View control is loaded with the data and the GridView is blank.  so how can i get the Post_ID field in the DetailView into the GridView.  Can someone please show me some detail example here?  C# is prefered in my case for the code behind.  Here is my field in the GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Post ID"> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox0" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: thanks for the tips, but i am newbie to asp can you give me some example?  thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most streamlined version of binding in this case I would modify the code like so:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack) {
DataTable results = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(getconnectionstring()))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM crudtable",connection))
    {
        results.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
    }
}

DetailsView.DataSource = results;
DetailsView.DataBind();

GridView.DataSource = results;
GridView.DataBind();
}
}
```

Then in your aspx file:

```
//Put gridview tags here
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Post ID"> 
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox0" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Firstname") %>'></asp:TextBox> 
        </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the gridview to the same datasource as your detailview.

Comment: thanks for the tips, but i am newbie to asp can you give me some example?  thanks for your time